# Different general solutions for extremely similar differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given: $y''' - 5y'' + 3y' + 9y = 0$ and $y''' + 3y'' + 3y' + y = 0$ .

*Find the general solution of the given high-order differential equations.*

Starting with the first:

1)  $y''' - 5y'' + 3y' + 9y = 0$.

**Step 1:**  $m^3 - 5m^2 + 3m + 9 = 0$.

**Step 2:** Using long division, factorize the above equation: $(m+1)(m^2-6m+9)$.

**Step 3:** You get: $m= - 1$ , $m= 3$ and $m= 3$ ($\Delta_{m^2-6m+9} = 0$).

**Step 4:** You get: $y = c_1e^{-x} + c_2e^{3x} + c_3xe^{3x}$

Do the second:

1)  $y''' + 3y'' + 3y' + y = 0$ .

**Step 1:**  $m^3 + 3m^2 + 3m + 1 = 0$.

**Step 2:** Using long division, factorize the above equation: $(m + 1)(m^2 + 2m + 1)$.

**Step 3:** You get: $m= - 1$ , $m= - 1$ and $m = -1$ ($\Delta_{m^2 + 2m + 1} = 0$).

**ATTENTION!**

**Step 4:** You get: $y = c_1e^{-x} + c_2xe^{-x} + c_3x^2e^{-x}$ instead of  $y = c_1e^{-x} + c_2e^{-x} + c_3xe^{-x}$.

Why? Why do we have different general solutions for extremely similar differential equations? This leaves me puzzled.

I know that the general formula for the repeated real roots in our case is: $y=c_1e^{m_1x} + c_2xe^{m_1x}$.

I'm not really interested to know how the general solution derived all I want to do is use it, so why is my solution manual (and even wolfram alpha) this form: $y=c_1xe^{m_1x} + c_2x^2e^{m1x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One critical difference is that the associated polynomial for the second is $(1+x)^{3}$; that means that $x = -1$ is a triply repeated zero, whereas for the first, you have a root and a double-root. The more common case is three distinct roots.

Such repeated zeroes are closely related to $+1$ values above the diagonal in the Jordan normal form: they represent elements that aren't QUITE eigenvectors for $\lambda$, but which, after multiplication by the matrix, become linear combinations of themselves and an eigenvector. That, in the ODE context, turns into "$xe^{-x}$, which is not quite $e^{-x}$, but after one differentiation, a linear combination of itself and $e^{-x}$". (Or two, or three differentiations, with $x^{2}$ or $x^3$ in front).